# "Clone" animation of a view

Tags: android

I'm looking for a method to produce a "Cloning" animation effect of a UI component.
Something that would look like simultaneously running multiple `TranslateAnimation`'s on the same view, while the view is copied for every single animation run, resulting in something similar to this pic:

[image: clone effect]

This has to run on at least API8 (2.2)

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: can you post answer.help me..

Answer (score 0):

Are the resulting cloned views backed by real cloned objects, or is it just a presentation thing?

If it would be ok to really clone the view, you could do that and then run an AnimationSet with two translation animations on the original and the cloned view.